# Check if YAML field is empty in twig

Tags: symfony, twig, yaml

I have two .yml files, in each one of them is a translation of my website. I reference the fields of the .yml files using twig. In one translation I need a field that in the other I don't. So in one translation I have to reference an empty field. But on the website there is not shown nothing but the "path" of the field. So I want to check if the field is not empty, how is it done?

YAML:

```
title
    1: string
    2: ~
```

HTML/Twig:

```
<h4> {{ 'title.1'|trans }}<sup>7</sup>
{% if 'title.2' is not empty %}
     {{ 'title.2'|trans }}
{% endif %}
</h4>
```

Website: String title.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `if 'title.2' is not empty` you test a concrete string to be empty, which will never be `false`. Even `if '' != 'title.2'|trans` might not work as it could fall back to a default language.

---

If you explicitly don't want to show a certain text based on the user's locale then test for that. It also makes your code easier to read and to maintain:

```
{% if 'en' != app.request.locale %}
    {{ 'title.2'|trans }}                    
{% endif %}
```

Even shorter:

```
{{ 'en' != app.request.locale ? 'title.2'|trans }}
```

---

I would also suggest using short words or phrases to identify translations instead of numbers.